# Upper value for shipping costs in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible to set maximum value of shipping costs in woo commerce?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the source](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Abstract_Order.html#1353), it looks like hooking into `woocommerce_order_amount_total_shipping` will allow you to modify the shipping total.

```
function max_shipping_filter( $shipping_total ) {
    $max = 79.00;
    return $shipping_total > $max ? $max : $shipping_total;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_amount_total_shipping', 'max_shipping_filter' );
```

Comment: OP asked "Is it possible" the correct answer would be **yes**, followed by an example.

Comment: @mevius you are right, I did read that wrong(my bad) I cannot change my vote however unless you edit your answer, so I guess it will stay, however if you edit it I will upvote ya! Thanks for all your entertainment today!